# d3 voronoi arc Map - control attributes of the .arcs

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, d3.js, selectall

I am using the voronoi arc map example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400 
And I can successfully visualise my dataset for import export trades.

However I am not able to change the properties of the individual paths generated at specific localities.
I use .airport-arcs to make those paths and I would like to have variable "stroke-width" or "color" of the individual lines. 
I have tried several options, such as :

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
...       
var td = svg.selectAll(".airport-arcs")
td.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.count); });
td.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.log(d.count); });
```

which appears to change all the stroke-width by the same quantity, while colors are different for all the links generated at a given locality (but different between localities).
Any suggestion on how to change the attributes for the individual paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You are not selecting the elements you are looking for. Selecting class `.airport-arcs` will return the group containing all paths. To manipulate the paths individually, you need to select like this:

   ```
   var td = svg.selectAll(".airport-arcs path")
   ```
2. You  are accessing the wrong property. `.count` is not a direct property of the data bound to the paths but of the airports' objects. `d.source.count` is what you are looking for.

Your corrected code would look like this:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var td = svg.selectAll(".airport-arcs path")
td.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.source.count); });
td.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.log(d.source.count); });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice, and yes I forgot to mention that I am new to d3 and JS.  I have tried your suggestion it in the example file liked above but it produces the same results I had before. Only the "color-per-group" is changed but not the individual path.....

Comment: @Patrizio Maybe, I don't get it. `count` is a value *per airport*. Therefore, `color(d.source.count)` will always return the same color for all flights starting at any given airport. Sounds like you are using the wrong criterion to determine the color.

Comment: count is a value per airport per destination. The same airport with different destinations might have different count values. Hence I would expect that based on [count] I can have different attributes for the different path.

Comment: I disagree: check the `airports.filter()` function. It sets `count` to be the number of all incoming or all outgoing flights whichever is greater and includes only those airports having `count > 0`. The last statement of the example gives another hint to my assumption setting the radius of the airports circle to be the square root of `count`. This only makes sense, if `count` is the number of flights *per airport*.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I have missed that line in the airports.filter(). I was looking at the flights.csv which has a count for each desstination. I will try to keep that info available in the script and then I suppose I can obtain the behavior I want. Thanks